# Unable to setup GCP Pub/sub subscription to BigQuery when BIGDECIMAL in target table schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

**Objective**: Setup a GCP Pub/sub subscription:

- on a topic associated to a protobuf schema
- which directly routes the JSON-encoded messages to a BigQuery table containing a `BIGNUMERIC` field

**Issue**: Creating the topic consistently errors out with a generic `API returned error: ‘Request contains an invalid argument.’`.

**What was attempted**: After many combinations of protobuf schema + target table schema, the conversion of any protobuf numeric type to a BigQuery `BIGNUMERIC` field seems to be the offending aspect.

I found [this official doc table](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#protobuf-to-zetasql) which describes the available conversions, and I notice that the target ZetaSQL types do not feature `BIGNUMERIC` at all.

**Question**: Am I missing something, or does it actually mean there is no way to do Pub/sub-to-BigQuery ingestion if the target table has a `BIGNUMERIC` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BIGNUMERIC` type is not currently supported in Pub/Sub to BigQuery subscriptions. The only way to ingest into BigQuery from Pub/Sub with this datatype would be to use Dataflow.